# Ant Design: How are they changing color on run time and so quick?

Tags: less, create-react-app, antd

I am using Ant Design in a React project. Ant provides styles in less which provides a way to customize theme and then build the code (less to css) but on their website (https://ant.design/docs/react/introduce) at the bottom they have a color picker which let you change the `@primary-color` instantly in over all places. No api call is being made and I tried to compile Ant Design less file i.e. `node_modules/antd/dist/antd.less` in browser but it takes few seconds (5-10) to compile. 
I also tried to do this using server side compilation by sending variables in POST request and then inserting returned css in DOM but that is not good.

I need help to achieve this functionality. Thanks in advance.
[image]

Comment: It's https://ant.design/color.less. Though when it comes to modern way of handling such things - this client-based mambo-shmambo is an outdated legacy (One would really consider using CSS custom properties instead).

Comment: Custom Properties are experimental. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*

Comment: So what? Do you think that a client-side script with *no* guaranteed responce time and with *no* active support by now is much  less "experimental"?

Comment: @seven-phases-max Don't take it personal. I am not here to argue about which is better and which is not. I've to do this with less. This is requirement, not a choice.

Answer (score 2):

My previous answer got deleted so adding some information here.

If you are using Ant Design then I've created a npm package called `antd-theme-generator` (or `antd-theme-webpack-plugin` if you are using webpack).

It allows you to specify which variables you want to dynamically update within browser and update color specific theme.

More info here https://github.com/mzohaibqc/antd-theme-generator

Here is demo
https://mzohaibqc.github.io/antd-theme-generator/

```js
const { generateTheme } = require('antd-theme-generator');

const options = {
  antDir: path.join(__dirname, './node_modules/antd'),
  stylesDir: path.join(__dirname, './src'), // all files with .less extension will be processed
  varFile: path.join(__dirname, './src/styles/variables.less'), // default path is Ant Design default.less file
  themeVariables: ['@primary-color'],
  outputFilePath: path.join(__dirname, './public/color.less') // if provided, file will be created with generated less/styles
  customColorRegexArray: [/^fade\(.*\)$/], // An array of regex codes to match your custom color variable values so that code can identify that it's a valid color. Make sure your regex does not adds false positives.
}

generateTheme(options).then(less => {
  console.log('Theme generated successfully');
})
.catch(error => {
  console.log('Error', error);
})
```

Comment: Would you please elaborate a bit more on how this works? I'm using AntD's CSS (not Less) and I only want to change AntD's primary color for dark mode at run-time, is it possible?